# Where should I put static text file?

Tags: android, mobile, smartface.io

I wanna include a text file to my project in smartface appstudio. I put it where? In resources folder or assets? FileStream could not read it in resources (as a drawable item). Any idea?

```
var txtFile = new SMF.IO.FileStream(SMF.IO.applicationResources, "words.txt", SMF.IO.StreamType.read);
txtFile.readToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not implemented in current release of Smartface App Studio. Also I have tried it before. It is Phase 2 for File Operations.

You can download your static text file from the internet and can save it to the local storage. And read it from there. I can just suggest you this idea. Check some helpful links below.

http://developer.smartface.io/hc/en-us/articles/203177557-File-Operations

http://developer.smartface.io/hc/en-us/articles/202153536-File-Download-Upload